# Permission errors with docker after OS upgrade

Tags: docker, file-permissions

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04, I get permission errors with any docker image. For example running `docker run -ti centos /bin/bash` gives me

```
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

I've never used the centos image before and the same happens with any image. Using chmod to set all permissions to /root and /root/.bashrc doesn't change this, neither does `apt purge docker` and reinstalling docker (or restarting the OS). I can run `touch /root/new_file` and `cat` the new file and `ls -n` shows the exact same permissions, user and group for the new file as for .bashrc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running this docker command as root? Make sure your user has the docker group. What docker version are you using? Install docker-ce.

Comment: It's probably not quite the solution, but definitely led me there, thanks! I had tried with sudo and made sure the user has the docker group with no help. In the end I removed the snap package for docker and installed the docker-io package from apt and the error disappeared.